# Varchar fields containing a single double quote get exported with two double quotes from snowflake web UI

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I have a table with a single Varchar column and a row with value A”B”C .
While downloading it from snowflake UI as a CSV file the result shows A””B””C
.

Answer (score 0):

In this case if you are using Data [Unloading feature](https://docs.snowflake.com/en/user-guide/data-unload-snowflake.html), you need to use File format in the copy into statement.
In the file format you need to use the option "FIELD_OPTIONALLY_ENCLOSED_BY "

Ref - https://docs.snowflake.com/en/user-guide/data-unload-considerations.html#empty-strings-and-null-values

When a field contains this character, escape it using the same character. For example, if the value is the double quote character and a field contains the string "A", escape the double quotes as follows: ""A"".

Comment: Hi Ansul,the issue I am facing while downloading from web UI using the download button.Data in table is with single double quote however in csv it’s with duplicate double quotes